# Python dictionary from file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary for firmware versions that I have installed on the server.
Where my goal is for the FQDD key to be equal to the Current Version value.

Everything works as it should, until I get to the network card keys:

NIC.Integrated and NIC.Embedded

For some reason the NIC.Integrated key receives the Current Version value of the NIC.Embedded key.
I tried to perform IF by ElementName, but still without success.
Any idea how to overcome this?

My code:

```
sw_info = {}
sw = {}
with open(f"sw_info.log", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            k, v = line.strip().split("=")
            sw_info[k.strip()] = v.strip()
        except:
            pass
        try:
            if "Broadcom Adv. Dual 10GBASE-T Ethernet" in sw_info['ElementName']:
                sw.update({sw_info['FQDD']: sw_info['Current Version']})
                print(sw_info['Current Version'])
            else:
                sw.update({sw_info['FQDD']: sw_info['Current Version']})
        except:
            pass

for key, value in sw.items():
    print(key,': ', value)
```

My firmware versions file:

```
-------------------------SOFTWARE INVENTORY------------------------

ComponentType = FIRMWARE
ElementName = Power Supply.Slot.1
FQDD = PSU.Slot.1
InstallationDate = 2022-09-03T18:32:38Z
Current Version = 00.21.33
HashValue = NA
-------------------------------------------------------------------

ComponentType = FIRMWARE
ElementName = Power Supply.Slot.2
FQDD = PSU.Slot.2
InstallationDate = 2022-09-03T18:32:38Z
Current Version = 00.21.33
HashValue = NA
-------------------------------------------------------------------

ComponentType = FIRMWARE
ElementName = Integrated Remote Access Controller
FQDD = iDRAC.Embedded.1-1
InstallationDate = NA
Rollback Version = 5.10.50.00
HashValue = NA
-------------------------------------------------------------------

ComponentType = FIRMWARE
ElementName = Integrated Remote Access Controller
FQDD = iDRAC.Embedded.1-1
InstallationDate = 2022-09-03T18:32:38Z
Current Version = 5.10.50.00
HashValue = NA
-------------------------------------------------------------------

ComponentType = FIRMWARE
ElementName = Broadcom Adv. Dual 10GBASE-T Ethernet - 84:16:0C:C3:4C:B1
FQDD = NIC.Integrated.1-2-1
InstallationDate = 2022-09-03T19:20:02Z
Current Version = 22.00.07.60
HashValue = 30df8d850c067b99136a6f1593cbbe74e4ce771a0e54283966b6de44ebcb495e
-------------------------------------------------------------------

ComponentType = FIRMWARE
ElementName = Broadcom Adv. Dual 10GBASE-T Ethernet - 84:16:0C:C3:4C:B0
FQDD = NIC.Integrated.1-1-1
InstallationDate = 2022-09-03T19:20:01Z
Current Version = 22.00.07.60
HashValue = 30df8d850c067b99136a6f1593cbbe74e4ce771a0e54283966b6de44ebcb495e
-------------------------------------------------------------------

ComponentType = FIRMWARE
ElementName = Broadcom Gigabit Ethernet BCM5720 - EC:2A:72:30:4E:9C
FQDD = NIC.Embedded.1-1-1
InstallationDate = 2022-09-03T19:19:59Z
Current Version = 22.00.6
HashValue = 56fa85676e6d570f714fb659f202371f1c570263b680e2d40d16059acfa9e3e6
-------------------------------------------------------------------

ComponentType = FIRMWARE
ElementName = Broadcom Gigabit Ethernet BCM5720 - EC:2A:72:30:4E:9D
FQDD = NIC.Embedded.2-1-1
InstallationDate = 2022-09-03T19:20:00Z
Current Version = 22.00.6
HashValue = 56fa85676e6d570f714fb659f202371f1c570263b680e2d40d16059acfa9e3e6
-------------------------------------------------------------------

ComponentType = FIRMWARE
ElementName = Broadcom Adv. Dual 10GBASE-T Ethernet - 84:16:0C:C3:4C:B1
FQDD = NIC.Integrated.1-2-1
InstallationDate = NA
Available Version = 22.00.07.60
HashValue = 30df8d850c067b99136a6f1593cbbe74e4ce771a0e54283966b6de44ebcb495e
-------------------------------------------------------------------

ComponentType = FIRMWARE
ElementName = Broadcom Adv. Dual 10GBASE-T Ethernet - 84:16:0C:C3:4C:B0
FQDD = NIC.Integrated.1-1-1
InstallationDate = NA
Available Version = 22.00.07.60
HashValue = 30df8d850c067b99136a6f1593cbbe74e4ce771a0e54283966b6de44ebcb495e
-------------------------------------------------------------------

ComponentType = FIRMWARE
ElementName = Broadcom Gigabit Ethernet BCM5720 - EC:2A:72:30:4E:9C
FQDD = NIC.Embedded.1-1-1
InstallationDate = NA
Available Version = 22.00.6
HashValue = 56fa85676e6d570f714fb659f202371f1c570263b680e2d40d16059acfa9e3e6
-------------------------------------------------------------------

ComponentType = FIRMWARE
ElementName = Broadcom Gigabit Ethernet BCM5720 - EC:2A:72:30:4E:9D
FQDD = NIC.Embedded.2-1-1
InstallationDate = NA
Available Version = 22.00.6
HashValue = 56fa85676e6d570f714fb659f202371f1c570263b680e2d40d16059acfa9e3e6
-------------------------------------------------------------------

ComponentType = FIRMWARE
ElementName = PERC H745 Front
FQDD = RAID.SL.3-1
InstallationDate = 2022-09-03T18:35:21Z
Current Version = 51.16.0-4076
HashValue = cdf6d5780d28c34e792c13e57c300ab46d964fdb1e1f189f7976044fa36d0092
-------------------------------------------------------------------

ComponentType = FIRMWARE
ElementName = PERC H745 Front
FQDD = RAID.SL.3-1
InstallationDate = NA
Available Version = 51.16.0-4076
HashValue = cdf6d5780d28c34e792c13e57c300ab46d964fdb1e1f189f7976044fa36d0092
-------------------------------------------------------------------

ComponentType = BIOS
ElementName = BIOS
FQDD = BIOS.Setup.1-1
InstallationDate = 2022-09-03T18:35:21Z
Current Version = 1.7.4
HashValue = 576f3516f12de1669552d56f0556b42a92e26b78db6c2c3486ec3e9cc144f0fe
-------------------------------------------------------------------

ComponentType = BIOS
ElementName = BIOS
FQDD = BIOS.Setup.1-1
InstallationDate = NA
Available Version = 1.7.4
HashValue = 576f3516f12de1669552d56f0556b42a92e26b78db6c2c3486ec3e9cc144f0fe
-------------------------------------------------------------------

ComponentType = APPLICATION
ElementName = Lifecycle Controller
FQDD = USC.Embedded.1:LC.Embedded.1
InstallationDate = 2022-09-03T18:32:42Z
Current Version = 5.10.50.00
HashValue = NA
-------------------------------------------------------------------

ComponentType = FIRMWARE
ElementName = System CPLD
FQDD = CPLD.Embedded.1
InstallationDate = 2022-09-03T18:32:42Z
Current Version = 1.0.7
HashValue = NA
-------------------------------------------------------------------

ComponentType = APPLICATION
ElementName = Identity Module(WWJ74)
FQDD = PM.Embedded.1
InstallationDate = 2022-09-03T20:31:07Z
Current Version = 2.00
HashValue = NA
-------------------------------------------------------------------

ComponentType = FIRMWARE
ElementName = TPM
FQDD = TPM.Integrated.1-1
InstallationDate = 2022-09-03T20:02:58Z
Current Version = 7.2.2.0
HashValue = NA
-------------------------------------------------------------------

ComponentType = APPLICATION
ElementName = Dell 64 Bit uEFI Diagnostics, version 4301, 4301A73, 4301.74
FQDD = Diagnostics.Embedded.1:LC.Embedded.1
InstallationDate = 2022-09-03T20:31:06Z
Current Version = 4301A73
HashValue = NA
-------------------------------------------------------------------

ComponentType = APPLICATION
ElementName = Dell OS Driver Pack, 22.07.10, A00
FQDD = DriverPack.Embedded.1:LC.Embedded.1
InstallationDate = 2022-09-03T20:31:06Z
Current Version = 22.07.10
HashValue = NA
-------------------------------------------------------------------

ComponentType = APPLICATION
ElementName = Dell EMC iDRAC Service Module Embedded Package v4.3.0.0, A00
FQDD = ServiceModule.Embedded.1
InstallationDate = 2022-09-03T20:31:07Z
Current Version = 4.3.0.0
HashValue = NA
-------------------------------------------------------------------

ComponentType = FIRMWARE
ElementName = Backplane 1
FQDD = RAID.Backplane.Firmware.1
InstallationDate = 2022-09-03T19:02:40Z
Current Version = 3.72
HashValue = b92e8c23b0caab9cc0a820f5a7aca1813b43c8ed93b533c76cd897dd7e2754d2
-------------------------------------------------------------------

ComponentType = FIRMWARE
ElementName = Backplane 1
FQDD = RAID.Backplane.Firmware.1
InstallationDate = NA
Available Version = 3.72
HashValue = b92e8c23b0caab9cc0a820f5a7aca1813b43c8ed93b533c76cd897dd7e2754d2
-------------------------------------------------------------------

ComponentType = FIRMWARE
ElementName = Disk 1 in Backplane 1 of RAID Controller in SL 3
FQDD = Disk.Bay.1:Enclosure.Internal.0-1:RAID.SL.3-1
InstallationDate = 2022-09-03T18:35:22Z
Current Version = BJ03
HashValue = NA
-------------------------------------------------------------------

ComponentType = FIRMWARE
ElementName = Disk 0 in Backplane 1 of RAID Controller in SL 3
FQDD = Disk.Bay.0:Enclosure.Internal.0-1:RAID.SL.3-1
InstallationDate = 2022-09-03T18:35:22Z
Current Version = BJ03
HashValue = NA
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinitialise your `sw_info` dict for each chunk (everytime a line occurs where you have `--------...`.
I think then you get the right result.

```
for line in f:
    if '-------------' in line:
        sw_info = {}
    try:
        k, v = line.strip().split("=")
        sw_info[k.strip()] = v.strip()
    except:
        pass
```